# perl persistent bloom filter

Tags: perl, bloom-filter

I have a system that runs multiple perl worker processes all of whom need to lookup a bloom filter. If I use the standard bloom filter perl modules ( Bloom::Filter or others ) every child process needs to add into bloomfilter
Is there a way I can use a bloomfilter that is shared across multiple processes

I need to even persist the data to disk, because every time I restart the system I can reuse the bloomfilter data

Comment: If one child process changes the filter, should the other child processes all see the change immediately?

Comment: there will be no change at all to the filters in run time

Comment: Then what you're looking for is called data serialization. Take a look at the Storable module. https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable

Comment: but that will mean the data will copied in memory for every child process

If I have 40million records in bloomfilter and 50 child then memory consumed would be enormous

Comment: How are you creating the child processes? `fork` uses copy-on-write, so if you load the data into the parent process before forking and don't modify it afterwards, all of the children should have access to it without blowing up your memory usage.

Comment: These processes are not forked but are started as individual processes

Comment: Then they're not "child" processes as you've been calling them. [IPC::Shareable](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Shareable) or a similar module might be helpful. There are many like it, just search for "perl shared memory." Here's [an example](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch16_13.htm) of how to use IPC::Shareable from the Perl Cookbook.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to approach this is to store the Bloom filter in a **shared data store**. A good system to support this kind of workload is [Redis](http://redis.io/). There are open-source implementations for [Ruby](https://github.com/igrigorik/bloomfilter-rb) and [Java](https://github.com/Baqend/Orestes-Bloomfilter).

If you only need a simple Bloom filter you can implement one with a Redis driver in a few lines yourself (taken from [one of my presentations](http://www.slideshare.net/felixgessert/nosql-data-stores-in-research-and-practice-icde-2016-tutorial-extended-version)):

[image]

[image]

**In short**: write the two methods above in Perl and you have a fully functional Bloom filter. To increase performance, avoid doing a round-trip for each SETBIT and GETBIT using [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) and compute the [optimal number of hash functions](https://github.com/Baqend/Orestes-Bloomfilter/blob/master/src/main/java/orestes/bloomfilter/FilterBuilder.java#L504).

The Java-based implementation achieves a throughput of roughly 250K insert and contain calls per second.